# How to use Webpack Hot Middleware / Webpack Hot Reload with IIS Rewrite / relative base Url?

Tags: node.js, webpack, hapi.js, webpack-hmr, webpack-hot-middleware

We are developing an application that uses hapi as webserver and webpack-hot-middleware for hot-module-replacement.

The application server runs at `http://hostname:8080`.

The application is usually accessible via `http://hostname/my/module/`
To make `http://hostname/my/module/` serve the application that runs under `hostname:8080`, we are using an IIS rewrite that rewrites everything from `http://hostname/my/module/(...)` to `http://hostname:8080/(...)`.

The issue now comes in when developing using `webpack-hot-middleware`. It seems, webpack hot-module-replacement always tries to make its *hmr* endpoint (I think the websocket for detecting/serving changes) *hardcoded* at `/__webpack_hmr` which - if the root page `http://hostname/my/module/` is opened - resolves to `http://hostname/__webpack_hmr`. Of course, this cannot be found and therefore returns a 404 since the IIS running at `http://hostname/` does not know anything about webpack hmr.

Now, for development, it would also be fine to access the application using its own address `http://hostname:8080/` but then, a CORS error happens:

> Access to resource at 'http://hostname/__webpack_hmr' from origin 'http://hostname:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So it seems even though I am accessing the application using `http://hostname:8080`, webpack-hmr still tries to open the socket at `http://hostname/__webpack_hmr` that then additionally fails with a CORS error.

Is there any option to tell the `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` that it should serve the `__webpack_hmr` endpoint as a relative path so it ends up as `http://hostname/my/module/__webpack_hmr` (which is rewritten to `http://hostname:8080/__webpack_hmr` which would be the correct address)?

Or if this is not possible, is there any way to at least get it working when accessing the application using `http://hostname:8080/(...)`?

I did not find anything in the docs. Only in some Github issues the Webpack `publicPath` configuration is mentioned but I did not see how it can help me.

**Update**
I came a bit further and detected that setting the `webpack-hot-middleware` entrypoint in the webpack config to `"webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://hostname/my/module/__webpack_hmr"` makes the __webpack_hmr endpoint be available at the correct location.

But the next issue now is that the HRM files

- `dist.XYZ.hot-update.json`
- `distbundle.XYZ.hot-update.js`
  are also tried to be located directly under the root directory (`/dist.XYZ.hot-update.json`, `/distbundle.XYZ.hot-update.js`).
  Is there any possibility to make these locations relative / set a specific subdirectory for them?

Adding another IIS rewrite to rewrite those paths to something like `http://localhost:8080/dist.XYZ.hot-update.json` makes it work but I would prefer a solution without having to configure the IIS for this.

Comment: hot-replacement is a feature for development phase in which ip:8080 is acceptable. For testing and production  in which a domain is required, is not recommend.

Comment: @JRichardsz the question is purely about development. But even in development, we require a hostname (the local machine's hostname).

Comment: If we are in development phase, in a linux desktop, the developer does not need domains or hostnames. Just npm run dev and open something like this: localhost:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080 and everything works. Developer does not need rewrite or another complex configurations related to networking. Maybe the problem is the use of IIS and windows for nodejs. These kind of technologies were born for linux, also in production environment, linux is the best choice. If your problem continues, Are you able to use another tools like apache or nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it without specifying the actual domain name and port

```
// Add hot reloading in development
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&path=/my/module/__webpack_hmr',
  ],
```

alternatively, you could use `dynamicPublicPath` and set the correct `publicPath`

```
// Add hot reloading in development
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&dynamicPublicPath=true',
  ],
```

check the documentation here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware